# при редактировании .htaccess выдает "Internal Server Error"

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, denwer

сайт стоит на denwer и вот содержимое .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

задача в том, чтобы убрать необходимость прописывать в адресе index.php/
Использую CodeIgniter. Никак не могу избавиться от этой приставки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что у вас такое `$1` первым параметром в `RewriteCond`? Вот в `ReriteRule` когда `$1` используется, там понятно. что это контент первой группы соответствиия в регулярке. Вы ведь наверное хотели строку запроса проверить, а не мифическое `$1` ?

Comment: @teran често сказать понимание лишь на интуитивном уровне, я в этом не разбирался

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте заменить содержимое файла кодом ниже:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Так же не забудьте в файле application/config/config.php заменить:

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php"
```

на

```
$config['index_page'] = ""
```

Comment: сделал как вы сказали. Но все равно ошибка. Заскринил и вставил в описание вопроса

Comment: Тут уже надо смотреть логи apache2 что вызывает ошибку 500, получается что файл .htaccess заработал и ошибка уже в php коде скорее всего

Answer (score 1):

исправил ошибку следующим кодом:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options -MultiViews
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

У Вас пропущено какое-то условие. Приведенное выражение содержит неверный параметр

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
```

Что такое `$1`? Еще ж не было разбора строки. Что это за первый аргумент?

Потому сервер и выдает ошибку

PS заметил, что частично дублирую комментарий teran.